# Writing graphml files - changing the node names to an attribute

Tags: r, graph, hyperlink, igraph

I have an igraph object (g_sub) that is a hyperlink graph, with the following attributes:

```
> g_sub
IGRAPH D--- 1331 11088 -- 
+ attr: Image File (v/c), Ringset (v/n), Country Code TLD (v/n), Generic TLD (v/n), Number of
  Pages (v/n), Modularity cluster (v/n), Categorical 1 (v/n), Categorical 2 (v/n), Categorical
  3 (v/n), id (v/c), Width (e/n), Tie Weight (e/n)
```

When I write `g_sub` to a graphml file, all the node names come out as "n0","n1", etc.

I would rather have the "id" attribute as the node names (i.e. each node is a website, so I want to see the URL, which is stored in the "id" attribute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in igraph and for a very good reason: node IDs must be unique in a GraphML file and they also have certain restrictions on what characters they may contain. igraph ensures these condition by constructing the IDs on its own as the file is being written - that's why they end up being `n0`, `n1` etc no matter what the node names are.

If you are interested in what characters are allowed in a "proper" GraphML ID, you have to first look at the [GraphML DTD](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/dtds/graphml.dtd), which specifies that `id` attributes are of type `ID`. Then you have to go to the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-attribute-types), which states that `id` attributes must be unique and that they must match the "name production". Then you have to find what the "name production" means within the same document: it essentially defines [a set of characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar) that are allowed within an ID. One example of a character that may appear in a URL but may not appear in a "name production" (such as an XML ID) is the hash mark, so you will get into trouble any time you try to use a URL containing a hash mark as an ID.

The only thing you can do is to post-process the GraphML file to use the URLs instead of the IDs. You can use any language that supports XML processing for that; I would probably do it in a separate Python script that replaces the values of the `id` attributes in each `<node>` tag with the value of a pre-defined attribute. However, one also has to make sure that the `source` and`target` attributes of `<edge>` tags are also replaced appropriately.